# PostgreSql Search JSON And Match Whole Term

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database using JSON storage. I have a table of cameras and lenses with a single property to search against called BrandAndModel. The relevant JSON portion looks like this and is stored in a column called "data":

```
"BrandAndModel": "nikon nikkor 50mm f/1.4 ai-s"
```

I have a LIKE query running against this brand and model string but it only returns a result of the sequence of characters matches. For instance, the above does get results for "nikkor 50mm" but NOT "nikon 50mm".

I'm no SQL expert and I'm not sure what I need to use to match more possible combinations.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM listing where data ->> 'Product' ->> 'BrandAndModel' like '%nikon 50mm%'
```

How could I get this query to match "nikon 50mm"?

Comment: to clarify, you want to filter rows where the `BrandAndModel` contains `nikon` and `50mm` but may also contain other words in between? do they have to come in that order? i.e. should `nikkor 50mm f/1.4 ai-s nikon` also match?

Comment: I just want to search for records that would match things like "nikon ai-s", "nikon 50mm", "nikkor 50mm". I guess that's a fuzzy match?

Comment: yeah, look into the extension `pg_trgm`. Otherwise, you could use a regex or `LIKE` with wildcards as in @Kaushik Nayak's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ANY` with an array for multiple  comparisons.

```
 LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%nikon%ai-s%', 'nikon%50mm%', '%nikkor%50mm%'])
```

Comment: The incoming string is from a search query so I don't have control over what that string is.